# Replace "find" for optimization in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a recursive jQuery function that has something like this:

```
parentItem.find('> div:first-child > span.c-checkbox > input[type="checkbox"]');
```

This runs great in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and even IE9. With IE8 and below it is horribly slow (15+ seconds).

I found in an article that IE8 performs bad with "find": http://ethermuse.blogspot.com/2011/07/jquery-find-slow-in-ie8.html.  I do not quite understand the concept. Can someone recommend a way to make this work properly in IE8?

**EDIT:**
I tried replacing the code snippet with this in my application and I think I noticed an improvement:

```
parentItem.children("div:first-child").children("span.c-checkbox").children("input[type=checkbox]")
```

Are the selectors identical and is there a way I can measure this?

Comment: replacing "find" with "children" shaved 10 seconds already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reduce the number of advanced selectors inside of *find()*.

Try this:

```
parentItem.find('input:checkbox');
```

Comment: Agreed, that seems like a horrible complex selector.  If needed, put a class on the checkbox and select it directly.  Or even better still, use an Id instead.

Answer (score 0):

it's not the `find` problem, but you should optimize your selector expression.

the best practice is use `id`, cause jQuery directly call `document.getElementById` to select node.

if you use such things like`$('.class')` `$(input[name=somename])`, there is no directly raw javascript method to do that, and jQuery would scan all the node to find which node you want, that cause the performance problem.

to solve your problem, you'd better specify an id to your element.

OR,

maybe you can paste out your HTML, so that i can write better selector for you :)